# jqGrid columnChooser does not shows effect for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have been trying to use `jqGrid` in my project, everything seems to be working fine except two scenarios  :-

1. When `columnChooser` is clicked for the first time, it will not show the effect on click of `done` button. It seems to be working for the second time. I have attached a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Vq7cWrnv9sa2k2RDU2cUV5YkU/view) and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbhmg9nq/)
2. I am unable to set height of `columnChooser`, if anybody can brief me how to do it.

PS: I am using [`free-jqgrid`](https://github.com/free-jqgrid)

Comment: Thank you for the bug report! I'll debug the code and will fix it. The problem with the `height` is known (see [the bug report](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/305), which I hold opened), but I just didn't found time to fix it. I'm busy now in other projects (which have no relation to jqGrid), but I'll try to find time to fix the problems in the next days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demo, which you posted uses **old version** of `ui.multiselect.js`: from free jqGrid 4.11.0. The problem is already fixed (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/f3c2490996c321552bc8915a732a0233d99fa8d0)) in the version 4.13.5. The current release of free jqGrid is 4.14.1. Replacing of the `ui.multiselect.js` and `ui.multiselect.css` to the latest state fix the problem, which you report: see the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/kbhmg9nq/1/.

The problem with the `height` of `columnChooser` is known (see [the bug report](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/305)). I'll try to fix the problem soon.

Answer (score 1):

I know about about how to set height of the `columChooser`

```
$("#bir").jqGrid('columnChooser', {dialog_opts :{ height:400}});
```